# pocketsphinx_continuous crashes at "reading HMM transition probablility matrices"

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I compiled with visual studio community.

The file that I originally wanted to test this on was over an hour long, so I tried it with a 3 second piece of audio, nevertheless, the same thing happened.
Here are the command line arguments that I used:

```
C:\path\to\pocketsphinx_continuous -infile C:\path\to\file.wav -hmm C:\path\to\en-us -kws_threshold 1e-40 -keyphrase "what I need to detect" -time yes
```

I was told to convert the file like this:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -ar 16000 -ac 1 file.wav
```

so I did, but I also tried it without the conversion.

When I run this the program seems to run okay, but then it crashes here:

```
INFO: tmat.c(206): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: en-us/transition_matrices
```

When run with the debug version of sphinxbase.dll, an alert pops up containing this:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: pocketsphinx_continuous.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\lowio\read.cpp
Line: 387

Expression: _osfile(fh) & FOPEN
```

just before the crash. I have tried everything I can think of, but nothing seems to work so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The crash is most likely caused by the mismatch in runtime. Probably when you loaded the project you somehow changed the runtime or just used different runtime for sphinxbase/pocketsphinx. You can use precompiled version available on website if you can't compile yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to have fixed this problem. I am not entirely sure why that was a problem, especially considering that I compiled sphinxbase myself and at least the dll is working (otherwise I would presume that pocketsphinx would crash). I have one other question. The output of pocketsphinx_continuous is very cryptic regarding the time that a phrase was uttered. I am given 3 decimal numbers side by side after the phrase I was looking for, but I don't know what they mean.

Comment: start time in seconds, end time in seconds and confidence of the match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download the file, in bin/Release are the, already compiled, binaries. Use these instead of compiling it yourself.

Thanks to Nikolay Shmyrev